# How to override a java class property variable in kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, inheritance, overriding

I am trying to override a java property variable in my kotlin class but keep getting the error "myVar overrides nothing". The example of how to override a kotlin class is [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html) but it doesn't say anything about overriding java properties. Here is the code:

```
//Java
public class myBaseClass{
    protected String myVar = "hello";

    public myBaseClass(){
    }

    protected void myOneMethod(){
        System.out.println(myVar);
    }
}


//Kotlin
class myChildClass() : myBaseClass() {
    override var myVar = "hi"

    override fun myOneMethod()
    {
        System.out.println(myVar)
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider creating a getter and setter for `myVar`

Comment: still the same error :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like that:

```
//Kotlin
class KotlinImplementation: MyBaseClass() {
    init {
        myVar = "ji"
    }
}

//Java
public class MyBaseClass {
    protected String myVar = "hello";

    public MyBaseClass(){
    }

    protected void myOneMethod(){
        System.out.println(myVar);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since Java doesn't have properties, you need to make the field private and provide a getter and setter. Then in Kotlin, you can override the getter and setter. It's not pretty, but this is how you would have to do it in a Java subclass as well. You need another private property to create the new backing field for your subclass implementation.

```java
public class MyBaseClass {
    private String myVar = "hello";

    public MyBaseClass(){
    }

    protected String getMyVar() {
        return myVar;
    }

    protected void setMyVar(String myVar) {
        this.myVar = myVar;
    }

    protected void myOneMethod(){
        System.out.println(getMyVar());
    }
}
```

```kotlin
class MyChildClass : MyBaseClass() {
    private var overriddenMyVar: String? = "hi"

    override fun getMyVar(): String? {
        return overriddenMyVar
    }

    override fun setMyVar(myVar: String?) {
        overriddenMyVar = myVar
    }
}
```

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val x : MyBaseClass = MyChildClass()
    x.myOneMethod() // Prints "hi"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Fields in Java cannot be overridden in any way.  Since `myVar` is a field in Java, it cannot be overridden in Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue in Java interop.

Here is a hack to overcome it:

1. Create an auxilary Java class, hiding problematic `protected` field:

```java
public class myBaseClassKtInterop extends myBaseClass {
    private String myVar;
}
```

2. In kotlin extend it; also consider adding `public` modifier for method, overring the `protected` one (if you don't do it, method [will remain](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html#classes-and-interfaces) `protected`; default public visibility is not working in this case):

```kotlin
class myChildClass : myBaseClassKtInterop() {
    var myVar = " hi"

    public override fun myOneMethod() {
        println(myVar)
    }
}
```

Now both ways to access `myVar` are working:

```kotlin
myChildClass().myOneMethod()  //hi
println(myChildClass().myVar) //hi
```

Also note that if there were another methods, accessing `myVar` in `myBaseClass`, they will be working with `"hello"` value. Consider overriding all of them too, or change `myVar` visibility to `private` in `myBaseClass` directly (if it is possible), in this case you will not need this auxilary class.